# InvalidOperationException - When executing a command, parameters must be exclusively database parameters or values

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

When I run the following ExecuteStoreQuery consitently throws an InvalidOperationException with the following message:

When executing a command, parameters must be exclusively database parameters or values.

```
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@pNetworkHealthAssessmentID", pNetworkHealthAssessmentID);
        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@pRiskAssessmentQuestionsID", pRiskAssessmentQuestionsID);
        SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@pUserID", UserID);
        SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@pSortOrder", pSortOrder);

        var result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_RiskAssessmentQuestion_Copy2Network @pNetworkHealthAssessmentID, @pRiskAssessmentQuestionsID, @pUserID", "@pSortOrder",
                                      param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

The Stored procedure's arguments look like this:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RiskAssessmentQuestion_Copy2Network] (
 @pNetworkHealthAssessmentID bigint
,@pRiskAssessmentQuestionsID bigint
,@pUserID bigint
,@pSortOrder int
)
```

Stored Procedure doesn't return any value back. Why am I getting that exception? I have tried every possible solution but so far unsuccessful

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not including that last parameter, `"pSortOrder"` was separated by a comma and it should be a part of the first string.

```
var result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_RiskAssessmentQuestion_Copy2Network @pNetworkHealthAssessmentID, @pRiskAssessmentQuestionsID, @pUserID, @pSortOrder"
, param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

Comment: Ohh I see what I'm doing wrong. Spent hours on this and didn't notice it.

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba - glad it helped. Please consider marking it as answer if it solved your problem.